# upload file to google cloud storage from app engine

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am able to write the small files to google cloud storage with the below code from google app engine. When I try to write bigger files getting memory exception.

Thinking may be it is writing entire file memory first then writing to google cloud storage. Is there any way I can download chunk by chunk and write to google cloud storage chunk by chunk. or is this issue completely different?

```
def _writeFilesinGCS(filename, data):
  ### Initializing Google cloud Storage Object
  print "In _writeFilesinGCS function"
  tmp_filenames_to_clean_up = []
  write_retry_params = _gcs.RetryParams(backoff_factor=1.1)
  gcs_file=_gcs.open(filename, 'w', content_type='text/plain',retry_params=write_retry_params)
  gcs_file.write(data.encode('utf-8'))
  gcs_file.close()
  tmp_filenames_to_clean_up.append(filename)

def download_files(service, report_run_id, report_fragment,loaddate,file_name,cfg):
  """Generate and print sample report.

  Args:
    service: An authorized Doublelcicksearch service.
    report_id: The ID DS has assigned to a report.
    report_fragment: The 0-based index of the file fragment from the files array.
  """
  bucket_name = cfg._gcsbucket
  bucket = '/' + bucket_name
  filename = bucket + '/' + file_name + "_"+ loaddate + "_MMA_" + loaddate + ".csv"
  print "Enter into download_files", report_run_id
  request = service.reports().getFile(reportId=report_run_id, reportFragment=report_fragment)
  _writeFilesinGCS(filename,request.execute())
  dsbqfuns._dsbqinsert(report_run_id,cfg,file_name,1)
```

Comment: You want to send the file directly to GCS storage and not use GAE as the middleman: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/simple-upload

Comment: What does `dsbqfuns._dsbqinsert()` do? That's in addition to just writing to GCS...

Comment: What does `bigger files` mean? How big is the file fragment represented by `report_fragment`? (side note: your GCS write needs to take that into account as well, currently fragments of the same file overwrite each-other)

Comment: i want to store the file directly in GCS. Python scripts are running in google app engine application. dsbqfuns._dsbqinsert() is just inserting an entry in bigquery to log purpose. Bigger files means service.reports().getFiles is download very bigger file(5GB)